# Rails 3: Changing input box length

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

Using Rails 3 with Twitter Bootstrap and Simple_form, I am having issues changing the length of the input box in this field:

```
<div class="input-prepend input-append">
   <%= f.input :price, :wrapper => :append do %>
      <span class="add-on">$</span>
      <%= f.input_field :price %>
      <span class="add-on">.00</span>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

Others say to add this after the :price variable:

```
:input_html => {:size => 15}
```

The 'do' loop seems to change the rules, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
:style => "width: 100px;"
```

Answer (score 1):

Twitter bootstrap has css classes for this. Depending on what size you want you can add class `input-min`, `input-small`, `input-large` and [so on](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms). You can also use the span classes, e.g. `span1`, `span2`, etc.

```
<div class="input-prepend input-append">
   <%= f.input :price, :wrapper => :append do %>
      <span class="add-on">$</span>
      <%= f.input_field :price, :class => 'input-medium' %>
      <span class="add-on">.00</span>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the `f.input` form to create controls with labels in a `:class => 'form-horizontal'` form, using a class attribute or style attribute (directly or as a hash, any way I tried) didn't work for me, and had zero effect on the generated HTML.

This is what worked for me:

```
<%= f.input :description, input_html: { class: 'span12' } %>
```

This works with both the Bootstrap column layout classes ('span1', 'span2', etc,) the input sizing classes ('input-large', 'input-xxlarge', etc,) or whatever custom class you want.  The trick is using the `input_html` key.  You can also mess with the label using the `label_html` key but that's likely to mess up the form-horizontal layout.

It looks like the size key in `:input_html => {**:size** => 15}` is ignored by SimpleForm... when I tired this it did not affect the HTML output.

I found this here in the SimpleForm docs:
[https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#usage](http://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#usage)

Comment: Please note that in order for inputs to be changed all over, in the form you can add `defaults: { input_html: { class: 'default_class' } }` instead of adding on each element, this may help you as it helped me...